# HttpInterceptor provided in Angular library is not working from Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing an Angular library where there is an authentication module that provides an `HttpInterceptor`. The main idea is to have this interceptor working automatically in any app that imports this authentication module without having to do any extra setup at it.

What I have so far is the following:

**AuthenticationModule**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ConcreteAuthModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: BearerInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthenticationModule {
  static forRoot(config: AuthConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthenticationModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AUTH_CONFIG,
          useValue: config
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**ConcreteAuthModule**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [ThirdPartyLibModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthenticationService,
      useClass: ConcreteAuthService
    }
  ]
})
export class ConcreteAuthModule { }
```

**BearerInterceptor**

```js
@Injectable()
export class BearerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headers: any = {};

    if (this.authService.isUserAuthenticated()) {
      headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${this.singleSignOnService.getUserToken()}`;
    }

    const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: headers });

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

And from a test Angular app I am importing this module the following way at the **AppModule**:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthenticationModule.forRoot({ /* config stuff */ })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I checked how some third party libraries did this, also came across a couple of Stack Overflow questions that discussed about this and they all suggested having an Angular module created (I already have it: `AuthenticationModule`), then provide the http-interceptor on it (already have it too) and finally importing this module from an Angular app (also did this).

But still, none of the http requests in my app are being intercepted.

Tried importing the `BearerInterceptor` directly from my test app and providing it on the **AppModule** like this:

```js
import { BearerInterceptor } from 'my-lib':

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthenticationModule.forRoot({ /* config stuff */ })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: BearerInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And that works! But this workaround is not what I am looking for...

Comment: what is your angular version?

Comment: @SheikAlthaf my Angular version is **8.1.0**

Comment: As for as i know that the interceptor depends on the HttpClientModule, so that the request passes directly from AppModule so AuthenticationModule interceptors not getting considers. I'm thinking like that, Maybe others will help.  FYI, https://angular.io/guide/http#http-interceptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I was installing the library locally for testing purposes like the following:

```
$ npm i --save my-lib_path/dist/my-lib
```

After I published it and installed it from the npm registry it worked fine:

```
$ npm i --save my-lib
```

Comment: Ha, I had the exact opposite!!  The app ran fine when using `npm link` to "install" my library into the app (similar effects, I think, as running your first command), but failed to even build when installing my library's package in the app the 'normal' way. My fix ended up being @Reactgular's solution

Answer (score 4):

You're very close to a working solution.

The key is to look at how the module is being imported by the `AppModule`.

```js
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthenticationModule.forRoot({ /* config stuff */ })
  ],
```

That is how the `AuthenticationModule` is imported by the `AppModule`, but that `NgModule` does not *provide* the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`.

You've provided the token in the `@NgModule()` decorator, but that module is not being used by your application. It's the module defined by the `forRoot()` function.

Move the declaration of the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` to the `forRoot()` function.

Try this instead:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [ConcreteAuthModule]
})
export class AuthenticationModule {
    static forRoot(config: AuthConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: AuthenticationModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: AUTH_CONFIG,
                    useValue: config
                }, {
                    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                    useClass: BearerInterceptor,
                    multi: true
                }
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This ended up being the fix for my issue (which is set up very similarly to OP's setup), but instead of not working (not intercepting), the app was failing to build at all because of an ngcc error: `Failed to find exported name of node ...` , referencing a completely random, unrelated file in my library  :|